# Using alias controller in templates to compile

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, compilation, controlleras

I'm unit testing a controller and I want to check whether the view is correctly updated.
Some field of the view are related to fields/functions of the controller.
When I try to get the compiled view, I'm not able to link the controller to the linking function with his constructor. 
I've created a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4iP3aA9msfxYke9wmkha?p=preview)

```
function($rootScope, $scope, $compile, $timeout) {
  $scope.helloScope = 'Hi Scope';
  this.hello = 'Hello';
  this.sayFunction = function() {
    return 'Function';
  };
  var template =
    "<div>{{helloScope}} {{main.hello}} {{main.sayFunction()}}</div>";

  $scope.toCompile = template;
  var newScope = $rootScope.$new();
  //newScope.main = this; //if I uncomment this line, all works!
  newScope.helloScope = 'Hi Scope';
  var el = angular.element(template);
  var linkFn = $compile(el);
  var view = linkFn(newScope,
      undefined, {transcludeControllers:{'main':this}});
  $timeout(function() {
    $scope.compiled = view.html();   
  });
 }
```

it works only when I add to the newScope a main property, so I suppose I'm not using the linkFn() function properly, but I have not been able to find any documents or examples about it.

[edit]
I've found in  [angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) that the third parameter for the linkFn is "transcludeControllers - an object hash with keys that map controller names to controller instances; if given, it will make the controllers available to directives.", but it seems not to work for me